# Colorize options in all helps' commands

Tags: command-line, zsh, colors, autocomplete

I have output of `sed` command as below:

```
sed --help
Usage: sed [OPTION]... {script-only-if-no-other-script} [input-file]...

  -n, --quiet, --silent
                 suppress automatic printing of pattern space
      --debug
                 annotate program execution
  -e script, --expression=script
                 add the script to the commands to be executed
  -f script-file, --file=script-file
                 add the contents of script-file to the commands to be executed
```

In my terminal `st`, it all white color in a black background that provide high contrast for me to work with.

Recently I change my mind, I want to change color of  all `-f script-file, --file=script-file` / `-e script, --expression=script` / `-n, --quiet, --silent` to a distinguished color than white -- yellow for e.g, howto?

I'm using zsh and st.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this ArchWiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/St#Colors), you 'd need to get the source code and alter C++ header and def file `config.h` and `config.def.h` and recompile the binary.

I'm not familiar with `st` myself but https://st.suckless.org/patches/ is having some community patches (see dracula etc.) hacking and guideline infos about st customization.

You could try oh-my-zsh which offers some themes, aliases etc. helpers for zsh, maybe this helps and it doesn't require to compile source code. https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh

Comment: Please help to give process how to colorize output of `sed --help` command as an example with `oh-my-zsh`. I think recompile every package is not possible for me.
`st` is just bit of extra info, I use customized `st` and here I'd need to color the exact `options` that listed in `--help` of commands.

Comment: You need to activate the zsh-syntax-highlighting plugin. Here is a pattern example for `rm`https://github.com/mattjj/my-oh-my-zsh/blob/master/plugins/zsh-syntax-highlighting/highlighters/pattern/README.md